# Minecraft PE on iPad Mobile Hotspot?

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have several iOS devices, one of which is an iPad 3 w/3G.  If I enable tethering, and the other iDevices connect to it, will it be possible to play Minecraft PE between all the devices?

Comment: yes. tested on ipad2(wifi+3g) and iphone 4.

Comment: @iMAGEbox Is there a reason you put your answer in a comment instead of in an answer?

Comment: nope there was no reason for that. i must put that?

Comment: @iMAGEbox: if you make it an answer, we can vote on it, and I can accept it.  You get points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this using the mobile hotspot feature of my CyanogenMod Android phone (a Samsung Captivate, though that shouldn't matter).  I *think* only the Captivate can host, in this case.  If other devices on the ad-hoc network try to host, the server isn't visible.

I did not get a chance to test it on the iPad, because I've had trouble setting up tethering there.

Minecraft PE *really* needs to add Bluetooth support...

Answer (score 1):

yes. tested on ipad2(wifi+3g/32gb) and iphone 4(16gb). mineraft pe serer is normal server like in minecraft but you can create only local wifi server(they are working on online servers now).